# Pip shows web socket error and I cannot install any packages

Tags: python, django, sockets, pip

I tried installing django but didn't work. Instead it gave me this error...

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions')': /simple/django/

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for django

I tried to install other packages and modules but none of them could be installed. I reinstalled python and while doing that I lose all my previous packages. I had a project with PyQt5 which I could install successfully two weeks ago but after I reinstalled python my packages, modules, etc. where gone and now pip won't work I don't know why.

I tried changing my network and tried using my phone's hotspot but it didnt solve the problem. I tried giving the version name of the packages but that didn't work either.

My network doesn't have a proxy or is not connected to a vpn. I can download any other stuff but I just cannot download stuff with pip.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what exact command did you run?

Comment: pip install django

Comment: what is your python version

Comment: it's python 3.8